# Vue js best way to pass child renderer as prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a component, which renders a table data. I want to pass a renderer function as a property so the table can be reused in multiple places and for multiple data types. I wonder what is the best practice for doing that: is it to pass a function which is called and returns an html:

```
<div v-html="renderCell(item)"></div>
```

or by passing a component name:

```
<component
    :is="itemComponent"
    :key="item[idKey]"
    :item="item">
</component>
```

Comment: You should use `slots` for reuse table
https://medium.com/corebuild-software/understanding-scoped-slots-in-vue-js-db5315a42391

Comment: @ittus - but I want to pass custom renderer except for the data itself. I want to pass list of items, and a way to render it. is it a function or component?

Comment: You can check this example https://codepen.io/ittus/pen/jxKBPx
List of items is passed as `<grid :rows="orders">` and the render way is passed as `<template scope="props">...`